# Parsing Large xml file

Tags: ruby, jruby

I have an XML file with size around 2GB. I found parsers which loads everything into memory. Can anyone suggest a parser/method that lazy loads the file into memory and parse?

Comment: Is this on xml document or are there many inside the file?

Comment: Try SAX style parsers like http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/SAX